# How do I reload a page in Javascript only after the new page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload

When reloading, I see a flash as the elements are being populated again. How can I prevent this by having the browser show the new page only once it has been fully reloaded (so that the user doesn't notice it being reloaded)?

Comment: Maybe first explain WHY you think you need to reload the page...

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to accomplish? You have a loaded page and want to reload it? It doesn't make sense. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: And the user will notice your reload in his browser

Comment: If you need to load something on the page from the server (or keep it updated), just use AJAX rather than reloading the entire page. You could use jQuery's [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (for GET requests), [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (for POST requests), or [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (a few more options). You could do a `setInterval` and every minute or so (depending on your needs) update whatever needs updating on the page (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Stack Overflow, etc. uses AJAX to update parts of the page rather than a full reload).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what it sounds you need to use ajax, post or get methods to reload certain parts of your site, not the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery uses the `.ready()` method, which is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready. So, initially set whatever is being reloaded to be invisible (`.hide()`) and then, for example:

```
$("div").ready(function()
{
    $(this).show();
}
```